# how to write a unit test case for the following code in a simple way in Junit, mockito

Tags: mockito, junit5

```
private Info getInfo(String id, String name){
        Info a = new Info();
        a.setId(id);
        a.setName(name);
        return a;
    }
```

How to write a unit test case for the method above?

Comment: Well, call the method, and check that the Info it returns has the right information. Mockito is useless here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    // Given
    String id = "myId";
    String name = "myName";

    // When
    Info result = getInfo(id, name);

    // Then
    Assert.assertNotNull(result);
    Assert.assertEquals(id, result.getId());
    Assert.assertEquals(name, result.getName());
}
```

I don't see why you would use Mockito for this test.